# Sum in a GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the below table format. What I am trying to do is updating the Annual Column where the ItemID is A-Sum and Annual Column calue is TotalSum to be the total of their ProductCode.

I tried but doesn't seem to work properly.

```
UPDATE  #MainCalcTemp SET Annual = (Select Sum(CAST(Annual AS decimal(18,3)))
        From    #MainCalcTemp S 
        Where S.ProductCode = #MainCalcTemp.ProductCode AND S.ItemId != 'A-Sum')
```

Here is my data:

```
ItemID  Annual      ProductCode
A-Sum   TotalSum    PHR
PHR1    12          PHR
PHR2    12          PHR
PHR3    10          PHR
A-Sum   TotalSum    LVA
LVA1    10          LVA
LVA2    10          LVA
LVA3    10          LVA
A-Sum               PQ
PQ1     11          PQ
```

Result

```
ItemID  Annual      ProductCode
A-Sum   34          PHR
PHR1    12          PHR
PHR2    12          PHR
PHR3    10          PHR
A-Sum   30          LVA
LVA1    10          LVA
LVA2    10          LVA
LVA3    10          LVA
A-Sum               PQ
PQ1     11          PQ
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, can you clarify what the difference is in the two data blocks? Is the first one your required result, and the second one is your intended result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an alias in update like this

```
UPDATE  A
SET A.Annual = (Select Sum(CAST(Annual AS decimal(18,3)))
              From    #MainCalcTemp S 
              Where S.ProductCode = A.ProductCode AND S.ItemId != 'A-Sum')
FROM #MainCalcTemp A
WHERE A.ItemId = 'A-Sum'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use window fucntions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*,
             sum(case when s.ItemId <> 'A-Sum' then convert(integer, annual) end) over (partition by productcode) as new_annual
      from #MainCalcTemp s
     )
update toupdate
    set annual = new_annual
    where ItemId = 'A-Sum';
```

You should also be careful about types.  I am guessing that `annual` is an integer, but that might not be true.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
UPDATE  #MainCalcTemp SET Annual = (Select Sum(CAST(Annual AS decimal(18,3)))
        From    #MainCalcTemp S 
        Where S.ProductCode = #MainCalcTemp.ProductCode AND S.ItemId <> 'A-Sum')
where ItemId = 'A-Sum'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution close to yours:

```
UPDATE T
    SET annual = (SELECT SUM(cast(annual as int)) FROM @tbl WHERE annual <> 'TotalSum' AND productCode = T.productCode GROUP BY productCode)
FROM #MainCalcTemp T
WHERE annual = 'TotalSum'
```